# Echo value from reassigned variable in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I'm newly writing a bash script. I have a configuration file that sets some variables:

#### `environment_information.conf`

```
SIT_SERVER_IP=xxx.xx.xx.xx
SIT_SERVER_PASSWORD=******
```

I read the conf file and try to echo with predefined keys

```
echo $SIT_SERVER_IP
echo $SIT_SERVER_PASSWORD
```

It is working fine without any problem.  In my scenario, I will read the values when executing a shell script.

#### `automation_script.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
. ./environment_information.conf
environment_name=$1"_SERVER_IP";
# test="${environment_prefix}";  # Error
test="${environment_name}";
echo "$.$test";
echo $SIT_SERVER_IP
```

I tried to get value from conf using input and some constant value:

```
$ ./automation_script.sh SIT
$.SIT_SERVER_IP
xxx.xx.xx.xx
$
```

It always prints `SIT_SERVER_IP` string.

But I'm expecting value from conf file for this `SIT_SERVER_IP`.

Comment: Please do not invalidate answers to your question.

Comment: can you first show your output of `echo $SIT_SERVER_IP` and `echo $SIT_SERVER_PASSWORD` or give an example, which can help me write some test script

Comment: Please show an abbreviated version of your configuration file.

Comment: Update question with configuration content

Comment: did these `SIT_SERVER_IP` and `SIT_SERVER_PASSWORD` are exported?

Comment: No,Why should it? because we read .conf ,then it will load all keys and values ? Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for indirect expansion (paragraph 4 of [Shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)):

```
test=${!environment_name}
```

This expands to the value of the variable whose name is held in `$environment_name`.

---

Proof of concept script, loosely based on your code (`automation_script.sh`):

```
: "${1:?}"  # Check that a parameter (SIT) was passed.

#. ./environment_information.conf
SIT_SERVER_IP="192.10.29.31"   # Surrogate for configuration file
SIT_SERVER_PASSWORD="secret"   # Surrogate for configuration file

echo "SIT_SERVER_IP=${SIT_SERVER_IP}"
echo "SIT_SERVER_PASSWORD=${SIT_SERVER_PASSWORD}"

environment_name="${1}_SERVER_IP"
echo "${environment_name}"
echo "${environment_name}=${!environment_name}"

environment_name="${1}_SERVER_PASSWORD"
echo "${environment_name}"
echo "${environment_name}=${!environment_name}"
```

Output from running the script:

```
$ bash automation_script.sh SIT
SIT_SERVER_IP=192.10.29.31
SIT_SERVER_PASSWORD=secret
SIT_SERVER_IP
SIT_SERVER_IP=192.10.29.31
SIT_SERVER_PASSWORD
SIT_SERVER_PASSWORD=secret
$
```

With the environment_information.conf file from the updated question:

```
: "${1:?}"

. ./environment_information.conf
#SIT_SERVER_IP="192.10.29.31"
#SIT_SERVER_PASSWORD="secret"

echo "SIT_SERVER_IP=${SIT_SERVER_IP}"
echo "SIT_SERVER_PASSWORD=${SIT_SERVER_PASSWORD}"

environment_name="${1}_SERVER_IP"
echo "${environment_name}"
echo "${environment_name}=${!environment_name}"

environment_name="${1}_SERVER_PASSWORD"
echo "${environment_name}"
echo "${environment_name}=${!environment_name}"
```

Running that yields:

```
$ bash automation_script.sh SIT
SIT_SERVER_IP=xxx.xx.xx.xx
SIT_SERVER_PASSWORD=******
SIT_SERVER_IP
SIT_SERVER_IP=xxx.xx.xx.xx
SIT_SERVER_PASSWORD
SIT_SERVER_PASSWORD=******
$
```

Comment: I tried this one. Noting printing. I'm getting empty value

Comment: See the update.  If you've got Bash as the question tag indicates, it should work.